# eclim .classpath commands not recognized

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, eclim

I've just started using eclim to code java. Everything seems to work fine except for the .classpath commands, such as :NewJarEntry or :NewSrcEntry. When I try these, I get, for example:

> E492: Not an editor command: NewJarEntry jgrapht.jar

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing your .classpath file — these commands should work from there.

Hope this helps!